# How can I have a scheduled email attachment dropped directly on server

Tags: php, email, csv, ftp, mailto

I get an email everyday with a csv file attachment, is there a way to have that automatically dropped on my server either via ftp (filezilla) or other method so I do not have to manually upload it to the server? My site uses PHP to populate the file and import it to my database.. I am not looking for the script necessarily but is it possible to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Sweet, any idea what the method is so I can start researching it?

Comment: There is no single "method". You need to learn how to connect via POP3 or IMAP to your email server, identify the appropriate email, download the attachment, then process it. Lot's of things to know and outside the scope of a single StackOverflow question.